# Как передать значения для тестирования view, которое написано на Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Вопрос, как протестировать функцию `delete`, которая принимает параметры через `post запрос`. Возможно использовать в тестовом случае `self.data`, где указывать основные параметры, которые приходят `post-запросом` и необходимы для его удаления?

```
def delete(self, request):
    post = PostCard.objects.get(id=request.data['post_id'])
    author = request.data['owner_id']
    if author == request.user.id:
        post.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
    else:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант использовать такой кейс [(офф. документация)](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/):

```
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase, URLPatternsTestCase
from django.urls import reverse
     class UserTestModule(APITestCase, URLPatternsTestCase):
         def test_can_user_delete_post(self):
             delete_path = reverse('delete_post') #Здесь delte_post это name вашего url 
             user_request = self.client.delete(delete_path, data={....}, format='json'
             #Далее добавляете необходимые вам проверки с помощью self.assertEqual
```

Хочу также заметить что, получение id объекта из request.data, это устаревшая модель реализации CRUD в REST, лучше передавать  его в url, как параметр. Например `post-crud/<int:pk>/`, а в view определить функцию [get_object](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/), для получения модели. Проверку на права доступа request.user к модели, лучше выносить в файл permissions.py. [Документация для permissions](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/)

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло.